# Cleanup of internal kafka streams with topology changes with schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I have a kafka application configured to use schema registry.  V1 of the app was deployed, and logs of intermediate topics were created in the topology (BranchChild, Reduce-State-Store,JoinThis etc). And, each of those had a schema registered with the schema registry.

v2 of the app is ready to go, but has significant topology changes. Deploying over the same topics/topology as v1 causes exceptions all over the place as the internal topics are now incorrect.  My 'user' topics remained consistent

Question: Is there a recommended method to resetting the application state other than blowing everything away and re-reading? 
Would deleting all the internal state stores and topics work?
kafka-streams.cleanup() won't touch the registry, which also needs to be cleansed.

Anyone have a clean solution / recommendation for this?

Comment: It might be simplest to use a new `application.id`.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Am I correct in thinking then that if there is a major topology change and internal kafka stores/topics change, then all those need to be purged and re-loaded; whether it's by deletion and offset resets, or by using a new application Id?

Comment: Yes. That is the recommended pattern. Delete all state and reprocess all input topics from "earliest".

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  If I have an app and in 3 years I make an application change that somehow changes how the internal topics are named (maybe add something so REDUCE-STATE-STORE-22 is now -23 etc.) It seems inefficient to have to reprocess everything

Comment: Correct. As of upcoming 2.4 release, you can name every Processor/StateStore/Repartition- and Changelog-topic to pin the names. That will allow save upgrades.